# What is a Vajrasattva?

Tags: vajrayana, bodhisattva

I recently heard the term Vajrasattva and wondered if that is another term for a Bodhisattva?  How does the Vajrasattva path differ from the path of a Bodhisattva?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vajrasattva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrasattva) is a specific bodhisattva, not another word for "bodhisattva." In esoteric traditions Vajrasattva is invoked as a counter measure to unwholesome actions. Esoteric traditions, and Tibetan traditions in particular, have elaborate explanations for the mechanics of karma+vipaka, and Vajrasattva is used as one of the [opponent powers](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Four_powers) of confessing misdeeds. The general idea is that strong enough opposition to harmful deeds performed can circumvent the ripening of "bad karma" and prevent the formation of harmful habits and lower rebirths.